# ICollection<T> calculate average per hour using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

For the following scenario how can I use LINQ in order to get the average per hour and per day:

```
public class Sales
{
    public Sales()
    {

    }

    public string Name { get; set;}
    public DateTime SaleDate { get; set;}
    public int Price { get; set;}           
}

ICollection<Sales> myCollection = new List<Sales>();
```

I know I can get the average like this from myCollection:

```
double average = myCollection.Average(a => a.Price);
```

what I need is to get the average per day:

```
date         average
24.09.2013   1243
25.09.2013   1278
26.09.2013   2587
```

and then average per hour for a specific date:

```
hours              average
00:00 - 01:00      125
01:00 - 02:00      127
02:00 - 03:00      158
```

and so forth ...

Comment: If you group the results by date/hour, it's not an average, it's a sum. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is it intended to average the individual prices?

Comment: @KendallFrey You can group by hour, then do an average within that hour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do average by date via:

```
var results = myCollection.GroupBy(i => i.SaleDate.Date)
                          .Select(g => new {Date = g.Key, Average = g.Average(a => a.Price) });

foreach(var result in results)
{
       Console.WriteLine("{0}  {1}", result.Date, result.Average);
}
```

To do average by hour for a given date:

```
var results = myCollection.Where(i => i.SaleDate.Date == theDate)
                          .GroupBy(i => i.SaleDate.Hour)
                          .Select(g => new {Hour = g.Key, Average = g.Average(a => a.Price) });

foreach(var result in results)
{
   var hourStart = TimeSpan.FromHours(result.Hour);
   var hourEnd = TimeSpan.FromHours(result.Hour + 1);
   Console.WriteLine("{0:hh\:mm} - {1:hh\:mm}  {1}", hourStart, hourEnd, result.Average);
}
```

Comment: I would group the _per hour_ on `GroupBy(item => new { Date = item.SaleDate.Date, Hour = item.SaleDate.Hour })`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen OP specifically asked for "average per hour for a specific date", not average per hour for all dates... I was trying to match the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Average per day can be done with:

```
var average = myCollection.GroupBy(item => item.SaleDate.Date)
                  .Select(item2 => new 
                  { 
                      Date = item2.Key, 
                      Average = item2.Average(a => a.Price) 
                  });
```

Average per hour can be done with:

```
var average2 = myCollection.GroupBy(item => new 
               { 
                   Date = item.SaleDate.Date, 
                   Hour = item.SaleDate.Hour,
                   DateTime = item.SaleDate })
                       .Select(item2 => new 
                       { 
                           Date = item2.Key.DateTime, 
                           Average = item2.Average(a => a.Price) 
                       });
```

Comment: I'll make an example to explain more.

Answer (score 3):

By date

```
var results = myCollection
                .GroupBy(i => i.SaleDate.Date)
                .Select(x => new { Date = x.Key, Avg = x.Average(y => y.Price)});
```

To calculate average by date and hour:

```
var results = myCollection
                .GroupBy(item => new {
                             Date = item.SaleDate.Date, 
                             Hour = item.SaleDate.Hour
                })
                .Select(x => new {
                             Date = x.Key.Date,
                             Hour = x.Key.Hour,
                             Avvg = x.Average(a => a.Price)
                });
```